# Manipulating an arbitrary-precision ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, manipulate, arbitrary-precision

I have a function, say

```
minimizeme[ω_][β_][ϵ_] = ϵ^2 ω-Log[2 (Cosh[2 β]+Cosh[2 β ϵ])]/(2 β);
```

I want to make a high-precision dynamic `ContourPlot` of it using:

```
plottricrit[ω_] := ContourPlot[
 D[minimizeme[ω][β][ϵ], ϵ] == 0,
 {β, 0.5, 1.0},
 {ϵ, -3, 3},
 Evaluated -> True, 
 ContourStyle -> Thick, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[
    {β, ϵ}, 
    minimizeme[ω][β][ϵ] < minimizeme[ω][β][0]],
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PerformanceGoal -> Accuracy,
 WorkingPrecision -> 60]

Manipulate[plottricrit[ω],{ω,0.217`60,0.22545`60}]
```

However, I keep running into a `ContourPlot::precw` message which tells me that

> The precision of the argument function (...) is less than
>   `WorkingPrecision`.

I have tried several ways to set the right precision (i.e., using `With` to inject a higher `$MachinePrecision`, using `SetPrecision`, using `Rationalize`, etc.), but I can't seem to get rid of this error. What is the right way to deal with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### New method

I found that using a step value that is arbitrary precision also works:

```
Manipulate[plottricrit[ω], {ω, 0.217`60, 0.22545`60, 1`60*^-6}]
```

#### Old method

For reference this was my original answer, which also works but is less clean:

```
plottricrit[ω0_] := With[{ω = SetPrecision[ω0, 100]},
   ContourPlot[D[minimizeme[ω][β][ϵ], ϵ] == 0, {β, 0.5, 1.},
   {ϵ, -3, 3}, Evaluated -> True, ContourStyle -> Thick,
   RegionFunction -> Function[{β, ϵ}, minimizeme[ω][β][ϵ] < minimizeme[ω][β][0]],
   ImageSize -> Large, PerformanceGoal -> Accuracy, WorkingPrecision -> 60]
 ]
```

Comment: Won't `SetPrecision` get me "virtual" precision?

Comment: @Andrea I'm sorry, I didn't read your question well enough; I was too busy editing in the Greek letters (I *do* wish there was a simple way to do that automatically).  Yes, this would be "fake" precision, but given that it is originating from a slider I don't see why that matters.  What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I hadn't thought about that. Since it is an input value, it is only as good as I can input it, and as it stands I can still use higher precision numbers via the input field under the slider if needed. Thanks! So, basically, there is no way to tell the Manipulate function to feed higher-precision numbers to its arguments "internally". Is this right?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard a nice palette for conversion?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I usually hate questions with non ascii symbols. Makes more difficult to work with the answers. I am thinking of a palette that when some text is selected and a button pressed changes all greek symbols into something ascii

Comment: @belisarius wait, are you saying you would rather have `\[Beta]` than `β`?  I'm trying to go *the other way*.  I could do it with a long replacement rule in a text editor but I'd rather have a "bookmarklet" or something like that, but I don't know how to write one.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I am saying that I would rather prefer to have `b1` instead of `β` (just to answer questions not to perform real work, of course)

Comment: @belisarius Okay.  Why?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Just because many new users get tangled into `\[Beta]` when posting code or comments. And I hate illegible code

Comment: Off topic but related to my comment: Is there a way to escape the backticks such that they don't break the inline code formatting?

Comment: @sebhofer use multiple backticks in a row to escape.  Here is a test: `one tick`, ``two`ticks``, ```three``ticks``` -- I'll take a look at the precision thing tomorrow.

Comment: Oohh... great, thanks!

Comment: I just found out, that if the boundaries of the interval are given as integer numbers, you have to specify the precision explicitly. Try for example ``Manipulate[Precision/@{x,y,{{x,2},0`32,10`32,1`32},{{y, 2},0,10,1`32}]``. (That's V.9 btw.) I think that is worth mentioning...