# Increasing number of decimal places in Manipulate input

Tags: manipulate, precision-and-accuracy

I've made a Manipulate app. in Mathematica where I vary the value of a function f(a) by varying the parameter a. However, I seem to only be able to edit my input for a for a value up to 5 decimal places (if I enter in a number with more than 5 decimal places, it rounds the figure). Is it possible to increase the number of decimal places with which I can enter in my value of a into the manipulate input?

Comment: I think similar things have been answered here. Search NumberForm and PrintPrecision.

Comment: Mike is right.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/annoying-display-truncation-of-numerical-results has the solution: `SetOptions[InputNotebook[], PrintPrecision -> 30]`

Answer (score 4):

Initially I forgot to specifically address `Manipulate`.  In addition to this post see also:

[Manipulating an arbitrary-precision ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8671/121)

---

This question may qualify as a duplicate (I'll let the community votes decide) but it has been asked in a different way so I'll answer it anew.

There are two issues that may be confounded here: input syntax and output formatting.

### Input syntax

By default a number entered with a decimal point that has less than 18 digits is interpreted as a machine precision number, while one with more is interpreted as [arbitrary precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3153/121):

```
12.                             // Precision
2.7182818284590452              // Precision
2718281828459045.2              // Precision
2.71828182845904523536028747135 // Precision
```

> MachinePrecision
>
> MachinePrecision
>
> MachinePrecision
>
> 29.4343

Any number (with or without a decimal point) can be [entered](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InputSyntax.html) with a specific precision by using the `` ` `` symbol.  A raw `` ` `` means MachinePrecision while e.g. `` `7 `` means seven digits of precision:

```
12`      // Precision
12.3`1   // Precision
3.14`20  // Precision
```

> MachinePrecision
>
> 1.
>
> 20.

Arithmetic between arbitrary and machine precision numbers automatically converts to machine precision:

```
12.3`1 * 17.2 // Precision
```

> MachinePrecision

See also: [Converting to machine precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7564/121)

### Output formatting

Machine precision numbers are by default automatically truncated to six digits in `OutputForm`, but more digits are still there internally:

```
2.7182818284590452 // InputForm
```

> 2.718281828459045

Methods to control this formatting are presented in: [Annoying display truncation of numerical results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121)

One of my own recommendations:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 10]

2.7182818284590452
```

> 2.718281828

This Option can be set globally: `$FrontEnd`, for a session: `$FrontEndSession`, for a particular Notebook: `EvaluationNotebook[]`, or even for a particular cell or expression (with the Option Inspector for Cells or `Style` for single expressions).