# Adding precision for the calculation of a function

Tags: arbitrary-precision, machine-precision

I have some function $f(x)$ I wish to evaluate, which is yielding divide-by-zero errors for sufficiently large inputs.  How do I increase the precision with which this function is evaluated in order to prevent this?  Can I do this while also plotting the function?

Comment: Related: [(3152)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3152/121), [(10624)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10624/121), [(13005)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13005/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight from the *Mathematica* [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetPrecision.html#61095731) of `SetPrecision`

```
bit = Log[10., 2.];
f[x_] := Module[{p = Precision[x], lx},
lx = Block[{$MaxPrecision = p, $MinPrecision = p},4*x*(1 - x)];
SetPrecision[lx, p - bit]]
```

then testing

```
x0 = N[1/3, 20];
fl = NestList[f, x0, 20]
```

As mentioned in the comment of your question, those related questions has got tons of tricks about precision management in Mathematica. I should be a bit more explanatory with my answer here.

**Problem:**

Lets evaluate this code.

```
{Sin[Exp[200.]], a + 2 b + 3 c, Sin[Exp[200]] > 0}
```

> {-0.89766,a+2 b+3 c,Sin[E^200]>0}

the above result comes with a error as the logical positivity test fails.

```
N::meprec: "Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating -Sin[E^200]."
```

Now an easy solution here will be to extend Mathematica's precision using the key `$MaxExtraPrecision`. This can be done in a `Block[]` construct to not have a global effect on the kernel.

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 150}, 
      {SetPrecision[#, 30] & /@ {N[Sin[Exp[200]], {Infinity, 30}], 
       a + 2 b + 3 c}, 
       Sin[Exp[200]] > 0}]
```

> {{-0.815597574752651427792149914303,a+2.00000000000000000000000000000b+3.00000000000000000000000000000 c},False}

One needs to be clear with the expression `N[Sin[Exp[200]], {Infinity, 30}]` where `Infinity` is the `Precision` and `30` is accuracy requested for the expression `Sin[Exp[200]]`.

You can use the block construct as above to define your function that require extra precision.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I added a bit from my limited understanding ;) Thx for the suggestion. Anybody please feel free to edit the answer to make it more useful and informative.