# Calibrating Precision in calculations

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

As the title says, I encounter an irritating problem which has to do with the accuracy or the precision used in the calculations. To be more specific, I have the following code:

```
Clear["Global`"];
Off[General::spell];

Vnuc[x_, y_, z_] := -Mn/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + cn^2] /. {Mn -> 0.08, 
cn -> 0.25};
Vdisk[x_, y_, z_] := -Md/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + (α + Sqrt[h^2 + z^2])^2] /. {Md
-> 0.82, α -> 3, h -> 0.1};
Vbar[G_, Mb_, a_, b_, c_, x_, y_, z_] := Module[{},
 m[u_] := Sqrt[x^2/(a^2 + u) + y^2/(b^2 + u) + z^2/(c^2 + u)];
 λ = If[m[0] > 1, u /. FindRoot[m[u]^2 == 1, {u, 1}], 0];
 Δ[u_] := Sqrt[(a^2 + u) (b^2 + u) (c^2 + u)];
 w000 = NIntegrate[1/Δ[u], {u, λ, \[Infinity]}];
 w100 = NIntegrate[1/Δ[u] 1/(a^2 + u), {u, λ, \[Infinity]}];
 w001 = NIntegrate[1/Δ[u] 1/(c^2 + u), {u, λ, \[Infinity]}];
 w010 = 2/Δ[λ] - w100 - w001;
 w110 = (w010 - w100)/(a^2 - b^2); w011 = (w001 - w010)/(b^2 - c^2);
 w101 = (w100 - w001)/(c^2 - a^2);
 w200 = 1/3 (2/(Δ[λ] (a^2 + λ)) - w110 - w101);
 w020 = 1/3 (2/(Δ[λ] (b^2 + λ)) - w011 - w110);
 w002 = 1/3 (2/(Δ[λ] (c^2 + λ)) - w101 - w011);
 w111 = (w110 - w011)/(c^2 - a^2);
 w120 = (w020 - w110)/(a^2 - b^2); w012 = (w002 - w011)/(b^2 - c^2);
 w201 = (w200 - w101)/(c^2 - a^2);
 w210 = (w110 - w200)/(a^2 - b^2); w021 = (w011 - w020)/(b^2 - c^2);
 w102 = (w101 - w002)/(c^2 - a^2);
 w300 = 1/5 (2/(Δ[λ] (a^2 + λ)^2) - w210 - w201);
 w030 = 1/5 (2/(Δ[λ] (b^2 + λ)^2) - w021 - w120);
 w003 = 1/5 (2/(Δ[λ] (c^2 + λ)^2) - w102 - w012);
 cc = 15/16 G Mb;
 pot = -(cc/6) (w000 - 6 x^2 y^2 z^2 w111 + 
   x^2 (x^2 (3 w200 - x^2 w300) + 
      3 (y^2 (2 w110 - y^2 w120 - x^2 w210) - w100)) + 
   y^2 (y^2 (3 w020 - y^2 w030) + 
      3 (z^2 (2 w011 - z^2 w012 - y^2 w021) - w010)) + 
   z^2 (z^2 (3 w002 - z^2 w003) + 
      3 (x^2 (2 w101 - x^2 w201 - z^2 w102) - w001)));
 pot
];

data1 = Table[Vnuc[x, y, 0] + Vdisk[x, y, 0] + 
Vbar[1, 0.1, 7, 1.5, 0.6, x, y, 0], {x, -10, 10, 0.5}, {y, -10, 
10, 0.5}];
data2 = Table[Vnuc[x, 0, z] + Vdisk[x, 0, z] + 
Vbar[1, 0.1, 7, 1.5, 0.6, x, 0, z], {x, -10, 10, 0.5}, {z, -10, 
10, 0.5}];
data3 = Table[Vnuc[0, y, z] + Vdisk[0, y, z] + 
Vbar[1, 0.1, 7, 1.5, 0.6, 0, y, z], {y, -10, 10, 0.5}, {z, -10, 
10, 0.5}];

Sxy = ListContourPlot[data1, ContourStyle -> Black, 
ContourShading -> False, DataRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
Sxz = ListContourPlot[data2, ContourStyle -> Black, 
ContourShading -> False, DataRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
Syz = ListContourPlot[data3, ContourStyle -> Black, 
ContourShading -> False, DataRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

However, when I try to create the three data tables `data1`, `data2` and `data3` the program reports several error messages regarding the precision on the `FindRoot` inside the module. Even if I tested a lot of variations for `MachinePrecision`, `WorkingPrecision`, `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` I could not solve this problem. Is there any other mistake that eludes me?

I would be really very grateful, if someone could help me out with this issue. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Make all inputs exact numbers e.g. 82/100 instead of 0.82. Then use option settings `WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6`. This will help for `data1` and `data2`. For `data3` it looks like you might need to consider nondefault `method` settings for the `NIntegrate` uses.

Answer (score 4):

If you `Rationalize` all your finite precision numbers and add `WorkingPrecision -> 50` to `FindRoot` the messages go away.  For example:

```
/. {Mn -> Rationalize[0.08], cn -> Rationalize[0.25]}
```

and:

```
Table[Vnuc[x, y, 0] + Vdisk[x, y, 0] + 
  Vbar[1, Rationalize[0.1], 7, Rationalize[1.5], Rationalize[0.6], x, y, 0], {x, -10, 10, 
  1/2}, {y, -10, 10, 1/2}]
```

See these posts for more information:

[Confused by (apparent) inconsistent precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10624/121)

[Adding precision for the calculation of a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17755/121)

[Funny behaviour when plotting a polynomial of high degree and large coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3152/121)

[Increasing number of decimal places in Manipulate input](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13005/121)

Comment: That worked only for tables `data1` and `data2`. Table `data3` reports errors regarding `NItegrate` this time.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z did you try increasing `WorkingPrecision` for `NIntegrate` as well?

Comment: If I add `WorkingPrecision -> 50` to the three `NItegrate` then errors appear in all three tables.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Okay, I guess there is more going on here than simply imprecise input.  I don't have time to exhaustively work through this code and I'm not that good with these particular tools anyway.  I hope someone else has an answer for you.  In the mean time you might search for the names of the messages you are getting to see if a similar situation has a solution you can use.