# Need help coding/creating a recursive list

Tags: programming, expression-construction

I have two lists `A` and `B`, each with 99 real numbers. I want to form a list, `C`, whose elements are functions (`F[]`) of `A` and `B`, and also previous elements of `C` itself.

```
C ={F[A1/B1], F[A2/(B2-A1/C1)], F[A3/(B3-A1/C1-A2/C2)], ..., F[A99/(B99-A1/C1...-A98/C98.)]}
```

where the integers after `A`, `B`, and `C`, are element indices.

I appreciate any tips on how to code this in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A pretty good puzzle, perhaps best solved using [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html). :-)

Note:  *you should not start user Symbol names with capital letters as these may conflict with internal functions.*

I use the carried expression of `FoldList` to keep track of three elements that are (re)used at each step.  These are `{sum, a0, c}`:

**sum**: the denominator apart from the current $b$ value.
**a0**: The $a$ value from the previous step.
**c**: the $c$ value from the previous step.

This triplet is then fed, along with the "current" $(a, b)$ pair to the function `next`.
At the end we take the third element of every list (the $c$ values), and drop the seed list `{0, 0, 1}`, done concisely with `Part` using `[[2;;, 3]]`.

```
aList = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"}; (* example data *)
bList = {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"}; (* example data *)

next[{sum_, a0_, c_}, {a_, b_}] := With[{x = sum - a0/c}, {x, a, f[a/(b + x)]}]

FoldList[next, {0, 0, 1}, {aList, bList}\[Transpose]][[2 ;;, 3]] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Addendum

If you wish to carry out this operation with arbitrary functions rather than a hard-coded `f` you might rewrite `next` to use a [SubValues pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/121):

```
next[f_][{sum_, a0_, c_}, {a_, b_}] := With[{x = sum - a0/c}, {x, a, f[a/(b + x)]}]
```

To use function `func` now in place of `f`:

```
FoldList[next[func], {0, 0, 1}, {aList, bList}\[Transpose]][[2 ;;, 3]]
```

Alternatively, and especially if your `f` is compilable you may wish to do something like this:

```
nextC[f_] :=
  Compile[{{old, _Real, 1}, {new, _Real, 1}},
    With[{x = old[[1]] - old[[2]]/old[[3]]}, {x, new[[1]], f[new[[1]]/(new[[2]] + x)]}]
  ]
```

This is an order of magnitude faster than the simple version on my test:

```
aList = RandomReal[99, 150000];
bList = RandomReal[77, 150000];

FoldList[next[Mod[#, 7] &], {0`, 0`, 1`}, {aList, bList}\[Transpose]][[2 ;;, 3]] // 
  Timing // First

FoldList[nextC[Mod[#, 7] &], {0`, 0`, 1`}, {aList, bList}\[Transpose]][[2 ;;, 3]] // 
  Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.624
>
> 0.062
> ```

Note my use of the backtick (`` ` ``) to declare the seed values as machine-precision Real numbers, to match the `Compile` function's specification.  See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13009/121) for more information.

Comment: Wow! Great! Thanks!

Comment: @Garcia I realize this may not be easy to read; as I said your question was a pretty good puzzle.  If you have trouble please let me know and I shall do my best to explain it.  I think I'll add a few notes to the answer proactively.

Comment: I am a retired scientist with years of experience with programming, but practically none with Mathematica. (I actually tried MuSimp/MuMath on a TRS-80 yrs ago :-) But I really enjoyed your answer....yea, enjoyed. I have a lot to learn.... thanks again.

Comment: @Garcia Thanks, it makes me happy to hear that.  I think you'll enjoy *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Garcia in case you read my Addendum and were confused by it: I pasted the wrong code into the body of the `nextC` function when I posted it; please look again.

Answer (score 5):

A little late to this question, but here is a fairly straightforward way to handle this. Define the two variable arrays by

```
m=4;
aa = Array[a, m];
bb = Array[b, m];
```

and then define functions that will create the arguments of `f`. For convenience, this can be broken into two pieces: `den` is the repetitive part of the denominator and `arg` is the argument of the function at the `n`th iteration. `bigC` calculates the intermediate values, and then the `Table` command creates the full desired vector (the `C` in the OPs notation, with the `C`'s fully substituted in).

```
den[n_] := Sum[aa[[i]]/c[i], {i, n}];
arg[n_] := aa[[n]]/(bb[[n]] - den[n - 1]);
bigC = f /@ arg /@ Range[m];
Table[c[i] = bigC[[i]], {i, m}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Mr. Wizard --- I missed that the c's were to be created from the previous entries in the big vector. I think I've fixed it up so it now agrees with the OPs request.

Comment: Nice simple fix. +1 :-)