# Can't figure out how to apply these functions repeatedly

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, functional-style

I have the following problem, and even though I've tried Fold & Inner, Sow & Reap, et al. I can't figure out the clean way to do this.

Here's the problem.  I have a list that starts as `{a,b}`. I want to apply the functions `f[u,v]` and `g[x,y,z]` a fixed number of times to this list.  The diagram below shows one iteration of what I want to do.

[image]

The next iteration would use this new list `{A,B,b}` as its input, as follows:

[image]

So after doing this a set number of times, I'd like the "result" to be the first two columns of these computations.  That is, if I did it two times (as above), I would be left with `{{a,A,`**A**`},{b,B,`**B**`}}`.

I can do this with a for loop of course, but I really believe there is a more "functional programmy" approach.  I know this isn't strictly about Mathematica, but it's the language I'm most comfortable with and it's related to a project I'm working on.

Comment: Thanks.  How can I recover the first two columns of the data though?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Related: [(21281)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21281/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f1[{a_, b_, ___}] := {a, f[a, b], b};
g1[{a_, B_, b_}] := {g[a, B, b], B, b};
NestList[g1[f1[#]] &, {a, b}, 2][[All, 1 ;; 2]] // TableForm

(*

a                                                b
g[a,f[a,b],b]                                    f[a,b]
g[g[a,f[a,b],b],f[g[a,f[a,b],b],f[a,b]],f[a,b]]  f[g[a,f[a,b],b],f[a,b]]
*)
```

To get your nomenclature you may use:

```
NestList[g1[f1[#]] &, {a, b}, 2][[All, 1 ;; 2]] //. 
         {f[a, b] :> B, g[a, B, b] :> A, f[A, B] :> BB, g[A, BB, B] :> AA} // Transpose

(*
 {{a, A, AA}, {b, B, BB}}
*)
```

Comment: I have another question which is similar, but is more difficult because this time the number of iterations is variable, based on the first list.  Should I just ask a new question?

Comment: @Guest You'll need to modify the `Nestlist[]` third parameter based on your arguments. Give it a try before asking

Comment: Oh but the problem is a little more complicated. Basically I need to do the iterations until the TOTAL of the first column is above a certain number. So if a+A+**A** is 9, then do another iteration, but if a+A+**A** is 10, stop. Here 10 is some fixed number.

Comment: @Guest So you'll need `NestWhileList[]` instead, but the same global logic applies

Comment: WOW! You must know every command! :)

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
With[{count = 3, start = {a, b}},
     Most /@ NestList[Composition[Prepend[Rest@#, g@@#]&,
                                  {#[[1]], f[#[[1]], #[[2]]], #[[2]]}&],
                      Append[start, 0], count]]
```

Explanation:

- `...&` defines an anonymous function. `#` accesses its argument, which is the list. `[[n]]` just gives the `n`th element of the list.
- `Composition` composes the two functions, that is, applies the right one first, and then the left one.
- `NestList` does the recursion, retaining the intermediate results.
- `Most` removes the last element.
- `/@` (`Map`) applies `Most` to each element of the list returned by `NestList`
- `Append[start, 0]` just adds a dummy argument to the initial list, so that `Most` can remove it again.

Comment: The problem is I need more than just the "end" of the iterations: I need the first two columns. That is, I need `Most` from every time these two functions are applied.

Comment: Ah, OK, I misunderstood that. I'll change the code accordingly.

Comment: @Guest: OK, I think now it does what you meant.